# Angular js dynamic checkbox and realtime data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have onclick function and datas in objects

```
$scope.messages = [
{"id": "1"},
{"id": "2"},
{"id": "3"},
{"id": "4"},
];

$scope.selection = {
   ids: {}
};

$scope.sendMe = function(message) {
    //send the data with `id` and `check state`
}

function onMessageArrived(response) {
_.each($scope.message, function (n, key) {
  if (responseID == n.id) {
    var boolValue = response.payloadString == 'true';
    $scope.selection.ids[n.id] = boolValue;
  }
});
}
```

now I'm loop with ng-repeat to create checkbox.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-class="message.type">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" ng-click="sendMe()" ng-model="selection.ids[message.id]"> 
</div>
```

It work fine but when the message arrived to my `arrived function`.
It add `$scope.selection.ids[n.id]` to `true` or `false` like

```
$scope.selection = { 
     ids: {"1": true}
}
```

But the problem is it not realtime update my checkbox.

what I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, what I'm missing is

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.selection.ids[n.id] = boolValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over `messages` like `ng-repeat="message in messages"`, but the `$scope.messages` variable is never updated. You should probably do `$scope.messages.push(message);` inside your `onMessageArrived` function